# Google authentification with Angular(17) and ASP.NET Core 8 Web API

Tags: c#, angular, google-oauth, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I'm working on a project using Angular 17 for the frontend and ASP.NET Core 8 Web API for the backend. I need to implement Google authentication to allow users to sign in using their Google accounts. I've searched for up-to-date resources, but most of them seem to be for older versions of Angular and ASP.NET Core.

Can someone provide a step-by-step guide or point me in the right direction for setting up Google authentication specifically with Angular 17 and ASP.NET Core 8 Web API? I want to ensure that the authentication flow is secure and follows best practices.

Also can it be done without creating a personal token and retrieving it to the user. Can I send the google one and check it with Google API with my backend.

Answer (score 1):

For using Angular 17 with google authentication you could refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@kushalghosh9899/authenticate-with-google-in-angular-17-via-oauth2-196a98793f0c).

Then inside the handleOauthResponse method, you could store the JWT token.

We will use this token inside the angular application to send request to the ASP.NET core web api.

For how to use google authentication to protect the asp.net core web api, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-8.0#configure-google-authentication).